# Error: AttributeError: module 'transformers' has no attribute 'TFBertModel'

Tags: nlp, tensorflow, pytorch, bert-language-model

I am applying transfer learning with the python framework (PyTorch). I am getting the below error, when loading a PyTorch pre-trained model in Google Colab. After changing the code 1 to be as code 2, I got the same error.

```
CODE 1:  BertModel.from_pretrained
CODE 2: TFBertModel.from_pretrained
Error: AttributeError: module 'transformers' has no attribute 'TFBertModel'
```

I tried to search the internet, but I didn't find any useful content.

Comment: Hi. You probably should provide the link to the Colab notebook with all your code.

Comment: are you using tensorflow 2.0?

Answer (score 4):

You should probably list the available package with its version in your python and your Colab link, for `TFBertModel` is only available when you have tensorflow.

In order to reproduce your error. I play around in the Colab as following:

1. No `tensorflow` cause error when you import `TFBertModel`

```
!pip install transformers
from transformers import BertModel, TFBertModel # no attribute 'TFBertModel'
!pip install tensorflow-gpu
from transformers import BertModel, TFBertModel # good to go
```

2. Directly use `BertModel`

```
!pip install transformers
from transformers import BertModel
BertModel.from_pretrained # good to go
```

As the result of my testing, you should probably check out if you import the `TFBertModel` while let tensorflow uninstalled.

Transformers under the master branch import the TFBertModel only `if is_tf_available()` is set to True. Here is the code for `if_is_tf_available()`:

```py
# transformers/src/transformers/file_utils.py 
# >>> 107 lines
def is_tf_available():
    return _tf_available

# >>> 48 lines
try:
    USE_TF = os.environ.get("USE_TF", "AUTO").upper()
    USE_TORCH = os.environ.get("USE_TORCH", "AUTO").upper()

    if USE_TF in ("1", "ON", "YES", "AUTO") and USE_TORCH not in ("1", "ON", "YES"):
        import tensorflow as tf

        assert hasattr(tf, "__version__") and int(tf.__version__[0]) >= 2
        _tf_available = True  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        logger.info("TensorFlow version {} available.".format(tf.__version__))
    else:
        logger.info("Disabling Tensorflow because USE_TORCH is set")
        _tf_available = False
except (ImportError, AssertionError):
    _tf_available = False  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
```